# SQL Server : delete specific data, ignore the rest

Tags: sql-server

The query below is used to find visits with more than one `resourceID`. This is fine and does its job. Then the goal is to keep specific resource IDs and delete the others. So for instance if the visit had resource IDs 1, 17 and 21 it should keep 1 and delete 17 and 21. This also works fine.

However if the visit does not contain at least one of the resources in the "keep" list, it should keep them all.

For example if a visit had resource IDs: 15,16,17 since at least one of those IDs are not in the list 1,2,3 and 4 it should not delete anything for that visit.

Not sure how to accomplish this. I thought about using a cursor, but want to avoid that if at all possible.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
;WITH CTE AS   
(
    SELECT
        pv.VisitId, COUNT(pr.ResourceId) AS Count
    FROM 
        Visit pv
    INNER JOIN
        VisitResource pr ON pv.VisitId = pr.VisitId
    WHERE   
        pv.Visit >= ISNULL('04/15/2016', '1/1/1900') 
        AND pv.Visit < dateadd(day, 1, ISNULL('04/21/2016', '1/1/3000'))
    GROUP BY  
        pv.VisitId
    HAVING 
        COUNT(pr.ResourceId) > 1
)
SELECT * 
INTO #Temp 
FROM CTE

DELETE FROM VisitResource 
WHERE VisitID IN (SELECT VisitID from #Temp) 
  AND ResourceId NOT IN (1,2,3,4)

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Expected results:

Delete 17 and 21.  This works.

```
VisitResourceId VisitId ResourceId
143              484    1
144              484    17
145              484    21
```

Do nothing, this does not work.

```
VisitResourceId VisitId ResourceId
146              485    15
147              485    16
148              485    17
```

Do nothing, this does work.

```
VisitResourceId VisitId ResourceId
149              486    1
150              486    2
151              486    3
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data with expected result ?

Comment: Yep I updated it, let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then perhaps something like the below example would work. It simply identifies all visits that have at least one resource on the "keep" list, and then deletes all resources not on the "keep" list that belong to one of those visits.

```
-- Define sample data from the question.
declare @Visit table (VisitId bigint, Visit date);
declare @VisitResource table (ResourceId bigint, VisitId bigint);

insert @Visit values (1, '2016-04-15'), (2, '2016-04-15');
insert @VisitResource values (1, 1), (15, 1), (16, 1), (15, 2), (16, 2);

declare @BeginDate date = '2016-04-15';
declare @EndDate date = '2016-04-22';

-- Step 1: Find all visits in the given date range that have one or more resources on the "keep" list.
with DeletionCandidateCTE as
(
    select
        V.VisitId
    from    
        @Visit V
    where
        V.Visit >= @BeginDate and
        V.Visit < @EndDate and
        exists (select 1 from @VisitResource R where R.ResourceId in (1, 2, 3, 4) and R.VisitId = V.VisitId)
)

-- Step 2: Delete all resources not on the "keep" list belonging to one of the visits identified in step 1.
delete 
    @VisitResource
where
    VisitId in (select C.VisitId from DeletionCandidateCTE C) and
    ResourceId not in (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: Yep that did it.  Thanks.  I always forget about `EXISTS` :)

Answer (score 1):

having seen the errors of my ways, you can just do this all in your CTE and not use a temp.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    VisitResource vr
    WHERE   EXISTS (
                SELECT  1 
                FROM    Visit v 
                WHERE   v.VisitId = vr.VisitId  
                        AND v.Visit >= ISNULL('04/15/2016', '1/1/1900') 
                        AND v.Visit < dateadd(day, 1, ISNULL('04/21/2016', '1/1/3000'))
            )
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT  1
                FROM    VisitResource r
                WHERE   r.ResourceId IN (1,2,3,4)
                        AND r.VisitId = vr.VisitId
            ) 
            AND vr.ResourceId NOT IN (1,2,3,4)
)
DELETE FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define `CTE` you can already filter out all visits where no ResourceId matches a element in the list:

```
;WITH CTE AS   
(
SELECT
    pv.VisitId, COUNT(pr.ResourceId) AS Count
FROM 
    Visit pv
INNER JOIN
    VisitResource pr ON pv.VisitId = pr.VisitId
WHERE   
    pv.Visit >= ISNULL('04/15/2016', '1/1/1900') 
    AND pv.Visit < dateadd(day, 1, ISNULL('04/21/2016', '1/1/3000'))
    AND pr.ResourceId IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY  
    pv.VisitId
HAVING 
    COUNT(pr.ResourceId) > 1
)
```

After that, the `Delete`will only handle entries with at least one valid ResourceId.

Comment: The problem is I need to return IDs that are not in the list if they are linked to a visit that does have IDs in the list.  I've actually tried using an IN clause as you suggest and I missed IDs that should have been deleted.